# VHDL - How to elegantly initialize an array of std_logic_vector?

Tags: memory, vhdl

I'm trying to interface to a classic HD44780 LCD.
I have implemented local ram to which I write the data I wish to show up on the display.

I have defined the ram in this way:

```
type ram_type is array (0 to (16*2)-1) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal lcd_mem : ram_type;
```

I've tried initializing the ram in this way:

```
lcd_mem(0 to 6) <= x"45_72_72_6F_72_73_3A";
...
```

But I receive an error on synthesis:

> Error (10515): VHDL type mismatch error at display_ber.vhd(74): ram_type type does not match string literal

Is there a way to ellegantly initialize the ram block in a similar way ?

Perhaps I should use a string type instead ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is.  Note that your definition of `ram_type` is an array of `std_logic_vector`.  And `x"45_72_72_6F_72_73_3A"` is a hex string literal.  These are not the same type, hence your error.

So, you have to put the value into an array of vectors.  Such as:

```
lcd_mem(0 to 6) <= (0 => x"45", 1 => x"72", 2 => x"72", 3 => x"6F", 4 => x"72", 5 => x"73", 6 => x"3A");
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is good. May also code as follows:

type init_type is array (0 to 6) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

constant c_lcd_int : init_type:= (45,72,72,6F,72,73,3A);

lcd_mem(0 to 6) <= c_lcd_int;

Comment: the hex numbers need to be specified as X"45" etc